# JSP taglib in a JAR file packaged in an EAR file

Tags: java, jsp, taglib, ear, jboss-4.2.x

I have the following situation:

- `taglib.jar`: A custom JSP taglib packaged as a JAR file. The TLD file is `/META-INF/taglib.tld`.
- `webapp.war`: A web application with JSP files that use the tags provided by `taglib.jar`.
- `app.ear`: A J2EE application which contains `webapp.war` and other WAR files.

I want to package a single `taglib.jar` in `app.ear` so the JSP files in `webapp.war` and the other WAR files can all use its tags. I tried the following directives in the JSP files, without success:

- `<%@ taglib uri="/taglib.jar" prefix="xxx" %>`
- `<%@ taglib uri="taglib.jar" prefix="xxx" %>`

Is it possible to package the JSP taglib JAR file in an EAR file? If yes, which value should I specify in the `uri` attribute of the `taglib` directive?

**Note:** I could of course package `taglib.jar` in the `/WEB-INF/lib` of each WAR file, but that is just what I try to avoid.

**Context:** I deploy the EAR file on JBoss 4.2.3.

**Edit:** I'm afraid this is impossible, especially since I read [the section about *skinny* WARs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/skinny-wars.html) from the [Maven WAR plugin documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin):

> Sometimes a list of JARs must be packaged into the WAR (...) in order for it to work properly, like with tag libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. The best I could do is to package `taglib.jar` in the EAR file, and duplicate the TLD file in the `/WEB-INF` directory of each WAR file.

Answer (score 1):

The jar taglib's can be only present under WEB-INF/lib. The container might provider some custom way to configure the commonly used tld. To achieve the same in JBOSS, this is the way

The JspServlet supports a new engineOptionsClass that allows the options implementation to be replaced. The default setting now uses the jboss specific JspServletOptions:

engineOptionsClass
org.jboss.web.tomcat.tc5.jasper.JspServletOptions

which in turn uses a custom tag lib descriptor cache org.jboss.web.tomcat.tc5.jasper.TagLibCache that loads tag libs from jars in the tomcat sar conf/tlds.

Comment: +1 since it seems it is indeed impossible to share taglibs in an EAR file.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old topic but I want to share my solution:
On eclipse right-click with mouse on the project, export as a jar with the option "Export generated class files and resources" and give a name to it (ex.customtags.jar).
Open the packaged .jar with 7Zip and we should see a structure similar to the following:

- com
- META-INF
- webapp
- .classpath

Copy all the taglibs to the META-INF folder **at the root** of the .jar file (not any other location).

After changing this jar add this to the webapp\WEB-INF\lib folder of the project you want to use the taglib.
On the jsp file put the following:

This should work just fine!

Regards,
MS